# Gradient colors not displaying for a button background in all versions of android

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a button with a background defined in an xml file so that it displays with the shape and colors etc. I choose.

Up until now I was working with an old api and this worked fine but since updating the code to the latest android version I find that the colors I set, while they work fine on an android 4 tablet I am testing with, no longer work on my old android 2.3.5 phone.
Instead the application seems to ignore my color choice and use (i'm guessing because it is some sort of default) a gradient of black to white (top to bottom respectively while angle is set to 270).  I can change the angle, so the xml file must be being used, but no matter what I set the start/end colors to they seem to be ignored.

the button background xml is as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>     
    <shape>
       <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/MyEndColor"
            android:startColor="@color/MyStartColor"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/MyStrokeColor"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="6dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="6dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and the layout xml defines the button as follows:

```
  <Button           
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstEditText"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/firstBtnIcon"              
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textColor="#AA000000"               
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="test"
    android:id="@+id/firstBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
   />
```

The button is inside a relativelayout within a scrollview.

Does anyone know of any api specific reason for this, or is there any known eclipse issue for upgrading projects? (I have tried cleaning the project but no change.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have stumbled upon the answer but I'm not sure of the logic behind it.
In order to confirm my problem was api related I changed my project back to target api 10 and it went back to displaying the button correctly.  In doing so I had to remove a line I had added to my activity:
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

I had added this line so some application options I wanted, could be displayed in an options pop-up (previously available through the devices physical front options button which has since been removed from android devices in favour of an optional on-screen button.)

Eventually I returned to the latest api but forgot to uncomment this line and low and behold, button still displays correctly. Uncomment the line and the button displays with the unwanted black and white gradient again.
I have therefore modified the code to say:

```
  if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10)//if past android 2
  {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);//so options can be displayed above android 2
  }
```

And now it works on both of my devices.  Thought I should post this in case anyone else comes across it but as I say, I'm not sure of the logic behind it under the hood of android.